# Como verificar se todos os elementos de um vetor estão entre - 4 e 4?

Tags: java, algoritmo

Quero comparar se todos os elementos de um vetor está entre -4 e 4, caso esteja, o algoritmo executará o método.

```
for(int i=0; i< j; i++){

   if(vet[i] > -4 && vet[i] <4)

   calcular(4);

}
```

Comment: Em qual linguagem? Não use *tags* do que não deseja.

Comment: Qualquer uma. Só quero ver a lógica.

Comment: Qual seria a dúvida? Me parece que a condição está correta.

Comment: Entendi agora. Vc quer verificar todos.

Comment: Isso msm...................

Comment: Será mais fácil limitar o escopo em apenas uma linguagem. As possíveis soluções para cada linguagem podem variar bastante entre si.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É mais fácil inverter a condição e sair rápido se tiver um elemento que não encaixe no filtro, assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void filtro(int tamanho, int vet[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) if (vet[i] <= -4 || vet[i] >= 4) return;
    printf("Está executando um método\n");
}
int main(void) {
    int vet[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    filtro(3, vet); //não considerará o último elemento que não encaixa no filtro
    printf("Agora não vai passar pelo filtro");
    filtro(4, vet);
}
```

[Veja funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/XU5QZF). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/cjtzmjpf-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/Condition.c).